# Showing $U(f,P) - L(f,P) \le K||P||(b-a)$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable real-valued function on $[a,b]$ such that $|f'(x)| \le K$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

I am trying to show that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) \le K||P||(b-a)$

How can I show that for any partition $P$, $U(f,P)-L(f,P) \le ||P||(f(b)-f(a))$ ?

where $||P||$ denotes the norm of partition $P$.

I know that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) = \sum_{r=0}^n(M_r-m_r)(x_r-x_{r-1})$

where $M_r$ denotes the supremum of $f$ in $[x_{r-1},x_r]$ and $m_r$ denotes the infimum of $f$ in $[x_{r-1},x_r]$

I can see that $x_r-x_{r-1} \le ||P||$ for every $r$.

If I prove this, I shall use the Mean Value Theorem and then I'll be done

Comment: This is not true (for example consider $f$ with $f(b)=f(a)$. (Or worse, note that $f(b)<f(a)$ would imply $U(f,P)<L(f,P)$.) I bet there's a hypothesis you're not telling us (for example is $f$ non-decreasing?)

Comment: In "I am trying to show that $U(f,P) - L(f,P) \le k||P||(b-a)$" the result is true.  The title does not match and is not true.  So presumably you want to show what you wrote in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by the mean value theorem, for any $x,y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]$ there exists $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$ such that

$$|f(x) -f(y)| = |f'(\xi)||x-y|\leqslant|f'(\xi)|(x_r - x_{r-1}) \leqslant K(x_r - x_{r-1}) \leqslant K\|P\|,$$

and

$$M_r - m_r = \sup_{x,y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]}|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant  K \|P\|$$

Thus,

$$U(f,P)-L(f,P) = \sum_{r=1}^n(M_r-m_r)(x_r-x_{r-1}) \leqslant \sum_{r=1}^nK\|P\|(x_r-x_{r-1}) = K\|P\|(b-a)$$

Comment: $|f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(c)(x-y)|$..right?

Comment: How did you write $M_r-m_r$ = supremum of that set?

Comment: @Gitika: For all $x,y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]$ we have $|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant \sup_{z \in [x_{r-1},x_r]} f(z) - \inf_{z \in [x_{r-1},x_r]} f(z)= M_r - m_r$. Hence $\sup_{x,y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]}|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant M_r - m_r$.  That direction is easy - agreed?

Comment: Also $f(x) - f(y) \leqslant |f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant \sup_{x,y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]}|f(x) - f(y)|$. Thus $M_r =\sup_{x \in [x_{r-1},x_r]}f(x) \leqslant f(y) +\sup_{x,y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]}|f(x) - f(y)| $ and $M_r - \sup_{x,y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]}|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant f(y)$.  Now take the infimum over $y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]$ to get $M_r - \sup_{x,y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]}|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant \inf_{x \in [x_{r-1},x_r]} f(y) = m_r$.  Rearrange to get $M_r - m_r \leqslant  \sup_{x,y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]}|f(x) - f(y)| $.

Comment: Therefore,  $M_r - m_r = \sup_{x,y \in [x_{r-1},x_r]}|f(x) - f(y)| $

Comment: Got it..Thanks a lot

Comment: @Gitika: You're welcome. I'll also fix my typo that you pointed out in your first comment.